# How can I resolve in my project Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 17'

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

Intialize connection

> System.ArgumentException:'Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 17'

The above error message shows on this line

```
    private void InitializeConnection()
    {
        server = "localhost";
        database = "table";
        uid = "root";
        password = "";
        string connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE" + database + ";" + "UID" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD" + password + ";";
        ObjConnection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString); // error happens here
    }
```

[image]

Comment: You're missing `=` for the Database, Uid and Password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code near `DATABASE` should be like `DATABASE=`, same way for `UID` and `PASSWORD`. All you were missing way `=` near these variables

```
private void InitializeConnection()
{
    server = "localhost";
    database = "table";
    uid = "root";
    password = "";
    string connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" + database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";
    ObjConnection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`MySqlConnectionStringBuilder` class](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/8.0/html/T_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlConnectionStringBuilder.htm) to format the connection string for you. It will handle concatenating the options and escaping special characters correctly.

```
private void InitializeConnection()
{
    var builder = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder
    {
        Server = "localhost",
        Database = "table",
        UserID = "root",
        Password = "",
    }

    string connectionString = builder.ConnectionString;
    ObjConnection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);

    // OR: ObjConnection = new MySqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString);
}
```

Comment: I'm enabled to submit data that i enter in form to the table in Mysql Server(XAMPP)